# Coefficient: how to simplify the "form"

Tags: filtering

The title is not very clear, but my English is not that good, so I didn't know how else to write it. So, let's get to the problem.

I have a list of elements, in form of a sum, like this:

$finalstate = \sum_{x_i} \prod_i A_{i,x_i} state[i,\alpha,x_i,j]$

where $\alpha$ and $j$ are unnecessary for this purpose, and "state" isn't initialized.

Now, $i$ is the index of a particle (I'm simulating a quantum system) and $x_i$ is its position.

Now, I want the coefficients for the coincidences. That is, the sums of the squared moduli of states which have every particle $i$ in their own position $x_i$, regardless of $\alpha$ and $j$.

For example, a 1 particle system would get me

```
Re[#.Conjugate[#] &[Coefficient[finalstate[[j]], {state[1, 0, i, j],state[1,1,i,j]}]]] (* for all i *)
```

For a two particle systems, I have instead

```
Re[#.Conjugate[#] &[Coefficient[finalstate[[j]], {state[1, 0, i, j]*state[2, 0, k, j],state[1, 0, i, j]*state[2, 1, k, j],state[1, 1, i, j]*state[2, 0, k, j],state[1, 1, i, j]*state[2, 1, k, j]}]]
```

(Don't mind the parenthesis, in my code they're correct).

Now, for three particles, i'd have to write a lot more. Is there a simpler way to do this?

(I hope my question is clear)

Comment: Can you give us an example of what `finalstate` looks like within your Mathematica code and what the output should be? I'm not sure what "coincidences" means, and providing more details about the structure of `finalstate` as well as what the output should look like would be helpful. (By the way, I'm not sure why $j$ is "unnecessary for this purpose", since it appears in the calculation you are doing!)

Comment: It seems to me that your question is really about how to generate the form given as the 2nd argument to `Coefficient`. I say this because all else is the same in your two examples. If I'm right, I suggest you edit your question, eliminating all the extraneous code, and reducing the two examples to what are now the 2nd arguments of `Coefficient`

Comment: I think you misunderstood, what I have is, for example

    finalstate = A state[1,0,0,j]*state[2,0,1,j]+ B state[1,1,0,j]*state[2,1,1,j]+ C state[1,0,2,j]*state[2,1,4,j]

And what I need are A and B, because in both, particle 1 is in position 0 AND particle 2 is in position 1, even if $\alpha$ and $j$ are different.

EDIT: I added the coefficient in the first expression.

Comment: What I mean is, I don't want to generate the sum, I want to filter between its elements to get their coefficients without writing all of them by hand.

Comment: Why did you change the edits that made your code more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you want. You can use `Cases` instead of `Coefficient` so that you can match patterns instead of the exact form, and as a side effect you can calculate the modulus at the same time.

Here is an example. Suppose that

```
finalstate[[j]] = a*state[1,0,0,j]*state[2,0,1,j]
  + b*state[1,1,0,j]*state[2,1,1,j]
  + c*state[1,0,2,j]*state[2,1,4,j]
```

Then doing

```
Cases[ Expand@finalstate[[j]]
  , a___ state[1, _, 0, _] state[2, _, 1, _] :> Abs[If[a === Null, 1, a]]^2
]
```

yields

```
{Abs[a]^2, Abs[b]^2}
```

The `Blank`s (i.e. `_`'s) match *anything* that is in that spot, so you need specify neither $\alpha$ nor $j$. The `If[a === Null, 1, a]` is a kluge to fix the problem that if the coefficient is 1, `a` is `Null`, and so an error will be thrown when trying to calculate `Abs[]^2`.

For three particles at respective positions 1, 3, and 4, say, we would do

```
Cases[ Expand@finalstate[[j]]
  , a___ state[1, _, 1, _] state[2, _, 3, _] state[3, _, 4, _] :> Abs[If[a === Null, 1, a]]^2
]
```

Comment: Perfect. I just added a `Total[ ]` around the result so i could have a single value. That was exactly what I was looking for, anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the accept, @Enzo, although it's usually a good idea to wait at least day or two to see if anyone else comes up with a better solution. It's also considered somewhat bad form to roll back edits that another user has made to make your code more readable. The changes that were made didn't change the content, only the formatting (and minimal changes to the title to make it more appealing to would-be answerers).